# cursor with sp_executesql and parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am hoping for some further help with an issue I have been struggling with, I did post a similar question yesterday but I think the example I was using was to complicated for what I wanted so I decided to start from scratch and write my own.

As previously stated I have a table with a number of sql statements in it and I want to run each in turn and update the same table with the result as well as the time that I ran the code.  My code so far runs through each SQL statement and executes it but I cant find either a way to update the Last_Result with the execution of each of the individual select statements i.e. ouput the value to a parameter e.g. @retval OUTPUT or even how to store it in a temp table with the ID so I can run a separate update later.
Knowing how to use @retval OUTPUT to set a parameter as well as how to update the table directly would be good from a learning perspective.
Can anyone shed some light on where I am going wrong as getting desperate now.

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_Run](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Script] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Last_Result] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Last_Runtime] [datetime] NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

declare @cursor nvarchar(4000)

set @cursor = 

'declare c_tables cursor fast_forward for 

select distinct
    ID,
    Name,
    Script
from Test_Run 
order by ID asc
'

exec sp_executesql @cursor

open c_tables 

    declare @ID varchar(2),
            @Name varchar(35),
            @Scripts nvarchar(3000),
            @Result as varchar(10),
            @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500),
            @retval as varchar(10) 

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT';

fetch next from c_tables into @ID, @Name, @Scripts

while @@fetch_status = 0 

begin 

-- insert into Test_Run(Last_Result)
 exec sp_executesql @Scripts, N'@ID',@ID;--,@ParmDefinition, @retvalOUT=@retval OUTPUT;

-- select @retval
fetch next from c_tables into @ID, @Name, @Scripts

end 

close c_tables 
deallocate c_tables
```

Comment: I don't understand why you declare and enumerate the cursor with sp_executesql. Is it necessary?

Comment: Hi Giorgos, this is not necessary but just the way I have been shown how to do similar things.  If there is an alternative that will help me solve the initial issue I am having I am all ears.

Comment: I will try to help you, and I need to understand your requirements clearly. First of all, what kind of statements are saved in your Test_Run table? Are they stored procedures, or plain SQL statements, or both? Can you show a couple of rows?

Comment: Hi Giorgos, the are just plain sql statement, it will be part of a wider system that I am designing to deliver email and txt message alerts when the values of these statements drop or exceed a threshold. These thresholds are dependent on the time of day and then depending on the result will deliver a email or text message but that is a little outside the scope of this question but just wanted to add some context  some examples are SELECT count(distinct name) FROM OurDatabase..job_failure_alert where job_id = '0C421646-2220-49C4-9C00-4568A160CF42' or 

select count(*) from OurDatabase..Cars

Comment: OK then, I think we are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do the job (and here is a [live demo](http://rextester.com/XIAY72434)):

```
declare 
    @id int, 
    @sql nvarchar(max), 
    @last_result nvarchar(100), 
    @last_runtime datetime,
    @params nvarchar(max);

SET @params = N'@retvalOUT varchar(max) OUTPUT';


select @id = min(id) from Test_Run;
while @id is not null
begin
    select @sql = Script from Test_Run where id = @id;
    set @sql = 'select @retvalOUT= (' + @sql + ')';
    exec sp_executesql @sql, @params, @retvalOUT = @last_result OUTPUT;
    set @last_runtime = getdate();

    update Test_Run set Last_Result = @last_result, Last_Runtime = @last_runtime where id = @id;

    select @id = min(id) from Test_Run where id > @id;
end
```

I removed the cursor completely and used a while loop instead - I guess I don't like cursors that much :-)

Comment: Giorgos, that is amazing, I never thought about setting the @sql like that and it looks far neater than my attempt.  I know I am trying to get in to the habit of using while loops but I tend to fine whatever I do they tend to get stuck in a loop but I can see what is happening here to stop this.  Its good to learn new things :) and I cant thank you enough for the help!!

Comment: You are welcome, actually it was fun! So if you think it solved your issue perhaps you should consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Sorry, thought I had clicked on that, glad you have shown me another way of doing what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, declare your cursor normally, so there is no need to employ an sp_executesql for it:

```
declare c_tables cursor fast_forward for 

select 
    ID,
    Name,
    Script
from Test_Run 
order by ID asc
```

Notice that I removed `distinct` keyword, I think `ID` is a candidate key.

Comment: Hi Giorgos, I have done as suggested, what would be the next step in accomplishing what I want.  My apologies for the distinct that was a legacy thing before I made the ID a key field

Comment: Is it safe to say that all your statement will have the form `select count(*) from ...`?

Comment: Sorry ;-) me being impatient as I want to see how much of a mess I am making of things.  Sometimes the result may be a string i.e select distinct but is a number of results come back I will be converting it to an XML another example select statement "SELECT count(distinct name) FROM quintegrity..job_failure_alert where job_id = '0C421646-2220-49C4-9C00-4568A160CF42'"

Comment: I don't understand: you cannot guarantee that each statement will have a scalar result? Then it's getting too difficult.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't explain myself properly but yes they will "all" have a scalar result.  The purpose of the alert is to show that there is an issue, for all statements that show there is a problem there will be a proper report that shows what is wrong that someone can run as and when they need to.

Answer (score 0):

The code that `sp_executesql` runs is in its own scope. Any variables and cursors created in that scope are not available outside.

In your case `c_tables` is created in the exec sql scope and thus does not exist for the `open` statement.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for the response, I think I understand what you mean but unsure how to fix my code to deal with this issue.